# Stroing child elements and events as properties of DOM Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, dom

How bad would it be if I could cache DOM selections and store them as property directly on DOM parent element. Say i have

```
(function(element){

element['content'] = element.querySelector(".tooltip__content");

//maybe event this
element['content']['handlers']['click'] = function(e){...};

}(document.querySelector("tooltip"));
```

This way I can "cache" DOM selection and have references to event handlers to use with removeEventListener.

How bad is it? What are the alternatives? Thank you.
Of course i can store it in seperate variables but maybe there is more structural organized way?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it... just a lot of ceremony and unnecessary boilerplate. If you're going to use the IFFE you can just store in vars, otherwise just attach to property.

Comment: Maybe one of the rare `WeakMap` usecases ...

Comment: Well, you risk a name collision with a native `.content` or `.handlers` property. Apart from that, you're fine.

Comment: @Bergi that is my foremost concern not to collude.